# Existence of a non-constant entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

> Which of the following statements are true?
>
> **a.** There exits a non-constant entire function which is bounded on the upper half plane $$H=\{z\in \mathbb C:Im(z)>0\}$$
>
> **b.** There exits a non-constant entire function which takes only real values on the imaginary axis
>
> **c.** There exists a non-constant entire function which is bounded on the imaginary axis.

*My try:*

**a.** Let $f$ be one such function.Then $|f(z)|\leq M$ whenever $y>0$ where $z=x+iy$. I was thinking to apply Liouville's theorem but could not do it.

**b.** Using Picard's theorem I find such a function can't exist .

**c.** I can't find a counter example here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: All three of these are possible. If it said "real axis" instead of imaginary axis for the last two, could you do it? For the first, pick a conformal equivalence with the disc.

Comment: Can you please explain how it is so?I am not getting it@MikeMiller

Comment: Is b is correct or incorrect @Learnmore how you applied Picard's theorem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**a.** $e^{iz}$ satisfies $|e^{iz}|=e^{-\text{Im}(y)}<1$

**b.** $iz$ as `Tim Raczkowski` told you.

**c.** $e^{z}$ is bounded on the imaginary axis. If $iz\in\mathbb{R}$ then $|e^{z}|=1$.

Comment: Could you please explain to me $(c)$?How does this show that $e^z$ is bounded on imaginary axis?

Answer (score 10):

Part b) is incorrect.  $f(z)=iz$ takes on real values on the imaginary axis.

Comment: Can you please help me with a and c

Comment: Why do you say part (b) is incorrect? It is correct right? The statement is true.